# How do I do field Validate and Check for Requested Fields with Sprinig WebFlow, Spring-JS, dojo, dijit

Tags: spring-mvc, dojo, spring-webflow, spring-js

How do I do field Validate and Check for Requested Fields with Sprinig WebFlow, Spring-JS, dojo.

I know I have to do something like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">                     Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ValidateAllDecoration({elementId:'proceed', event:'onclick'}));
</script>
```

and

```
<form:input path="creditCardName" maxlength="40"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration({
    elementId : "creditCardName",
    widgetType : "dijit.form.ValidationTextBox",
    widgetAttrs : { required : true }}));
</script>
```

is this all I have to do?

Comment: yes, that's all you have to do. are you having any issues?

Comment: yes on the submit it does not display any popup message or anything

Comment: does it submit the form? it is supposed to show a little attention sign and say "this field is required" on the FIELD itself